# Magento remove tabs like invoices,credit memos,shipment in admin sales order view using observer

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer, sales-order, tabs

I want to remove tabs(invoice,credit memo,shipment) in sales order view using observer
My `config.xml` file

```
    <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                        <observers>
                            <package_test_adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                                <class>test/observer</class>
                                <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                            </package_test_adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                        </observers>
    </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
```

My `observer.php`

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event) 
    {
        $block = $event->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs) {
            $block->removeTab('order_tab_info'); // I am trying information tab from sales order view but it doesn't work          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In config.xml use **core_block_abstract_to_html_before** instead **adminhtml_widget_container_html_before**

```
<events>
    <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        <observers>
            <package_test_adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
                <class>test/observer</class>
                <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
            </package_test_adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
        </observers>
    </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
</events>
```

and replace your observer **adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore()** with:

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event) {
    $block = $event->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tabs) {
        $block->removeTab('order_transactions');   // Remove tab by id
        $block->removeTab('order_history');        // Remove tab by id
    }
}
```

Note: Please don't try to remove sales order view current active tab, it will thrown below error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Tabs.php on line 236, referer: http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/47b8c63b239bfb55d90a12088f642fed/
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You copy your local then check

```
**Remove Credit memo**

    app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\View\Tab\Creditmemos.php

    public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true; // Set false Here
        }


    **Remove Invoices**

    app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\View\Tab\Invoices.php

    public function canShowTab()
        {
            return true; //Set false
        }

    **Remove Shipments**

         app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\View\Tab\Shipments.php


    public function canShowTab()
        {
            if ($this->getOrder()->getIsVirtual()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true; //set false here
        }
```

Comment: I know this solution but this approach done by three time override block file, but I want with this by observer

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace you code with following

```
public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event) 
{
    $block = $event->getBlock();
    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs) {
        $block->removeTab('order_info'); // Check the tab name
    }
}
```